# Data fetching with useDispatch inside useEffect (code work but with error)

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, use-effect

I tried to use useEffect for fetching data from API with useDispatch hook:

```
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {dispatch(actions.fetchSearch(submitValue))}, [submitValue, dispatch]);
```

Where *submitValue* - it is an input value for search query. fetchSearch() looks like this:

```
export const fetchSearch = (query) => {
return dispatch => {
    const queryParams = 'http://190.75.199.65/api/products?count=20&sort_by=numberOfEntries&sort_order=DESC&page=1&search='+query;
    axios.get(queryParams)
    .then( res=> {
            dispatch(fetchSearchSuccess(res.data));
        }
    )
};
```

};

I can fetch data by this code, but an error occured all the time:

> An effect function must not return anything besides a function, which
>   is used for clean-up.
>
> It looks like you wrote useEffect(async () => ...) or returned a
>   Promise. Instead, write the async function inside your effect and call
>   it immediately

I tried to make async function inside useEffect, but error is same or maybe I make something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to do this:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();

useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
     await dispatch(actions.fetchSearch(submitValue));
    })();
}, [submitValue, dispatch]);
```

I think it is because you are directly calling a async function and it is returning a promise in useEffect.

Comment: hey, try to add async in the inner function

Comment: code work now, I forgot to remove another useEffect!  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

code work without any changes

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();

useEffect(() => {dispatch(actions.fetchSearch(submitValue))}, [submitValue, dispatch]);
```

just forgot to remove old useEffect.